# Integration testing EJB3 in-container

Tags: jakarta-ee, testing, integration-testing, ejb-3.0, jboss-arquillian

Are there currently some recommendable ways to do EJB3 testing on the target container (in our case Websphere)?
Arquillian was not working for us as we have a huge project with a lot of interdependencies which made any kind of microdeployments impossible. Also we had problems deploying the whole aplication using arquillian as it seems not to work with websphere as well as with other containers.

Is the cactus framework still a valid option to do java ee6/ejb3 integration tests?
It seems outdated as it was retired in 2011.. Are there any other options besides Arquillian?

Comment: Arquillian is the best way to move forward. Even ours is huge legacy project and we were able to modify few configs and our arquillian setup is up and running. Can you please share where you are facing issue in configuring the same?

Comment: even in a really simple case with only one class and one testclass depicting our setup arquillian failed to inject the ejb half of the time. with the whole project deployed (there was no way around this) we faced issue after issue with very generic errormessages. it just doesn't looked like arquillian+websphere 8 will ever work for us in this current setup

Comment: how did you deploy your project? did you include all the dependencies of the class you are trying to test as part of the deployable? what is the error that you are facing while deploying?